# Watch for changes in Angular 2 services function

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a service named **HomeService**  and in that service I am setting and getting some data which is working fine. Here is the code for my service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {

name:string;

constructor() { }

setParams(val) {
      this.name = val;
}
getParams() {
    return this.name;
}

}
```

I am setting params in a **component A** and getting it in **component B**. What I want is to keep watching the **getParams()** for changing in the second component.
I am getting the params value in **component A** in which I am setting it but I couldn't get those value in **Component B**. Means in **Component B** its not watching for changes.

Comment: I have added an answer to achieve your need. Please look at it. You have to use an observable to get this working, so it subscribes for the param and whenever a change is made it updates the value in the component

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To track the changes of the name property you have to use observables.
Change your service as below.

**HomeService:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {

    private nameSource = new Subject<any>();

    name$ = this.nameSource.asObservable();

    setParams(val) {
        this.nameSource.next(val);
    }

}
```

In your component B where you want the name to be changed, It always keep subscribed to the name in the service. So that whenever the name is changed in the service (When you set the name fro Component A), You can track the change and Component B will get updated.

**ComponentB:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeWhile';
import { HomeService } from '[add path of home service here]';

export class ComponentBComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

    private alive: boolean = true;
    private name: string;

    constructor(
        private homeService: HomeService;
    ) {
        homeService.name$.takeWhile(() => this.alive).subscribe(
            name=> {
                this.name = name;
        });

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // Whatever to happen OnInit
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.alive = false;
    }

}
```

Please note that the `takeWhile()` and `alive` are used to [prevent memory leaks.](http://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/)

From whatever the place you set the name to Home service,

```
this.homeService.setParams(name);
```

This solution should work for you.

Comment: thanks it worked for me. Just need to study more about the observable in detail.

Comment: @AhmerKhan So, this is component interaction. Going through this will help you to decide, which technique that you can use for the different kinda scenarios. Happy coding.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: This is a great solution and it worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Consider re-logicate it with service based on subscribtion. In components you have to subscribe `observable` variable which is based on source, and whenever you call `next` method on source, the observable is firing and components that have subscribe this observable will receive new/updated value and inside `subscribe` callback you can define what would you do with that value. For more information check this [article](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service).